# Get the time of App launcehed Android

Tags: android, time

I want to get the time when the app launched.the time should be in milliseconds. Any suggetions please...

Answer (score 0):

When you start your `Activity`, just call `System.currentTimeMillis()` and store it in a variable. Up to you where you want to do that: either in `onCreate()`, where your `Activity` and other inside elements are "inflated" or instantiated, or `onResume()`, when the `Activity` surfaces on the screen.

Example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    long timeOpened = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

long lDateTime = new Date().getTime(); you can used this code in your mainActivity in Oncreate . When your MainActivity call this code execute and you get the time in milisecond

Or you can used long time=System.currentTimeMillis(); this also given current time in milisecond